# I'm a little bit unsure about my use case diagram

Tags: uml, software-design, use-case

My teacher just gave me a task to create a use case diagram based on her given use cases and I have 2 actors which is Admin and Inventory officer and they are most likely the same to each other, but I'm not sure enough if I'm doing it right.

[image: Here is my work]

This is the use cases my teacher gave to me:

```
Administrator(Actor)        
Add User Account        
Update User Account     
Deactivate User Account     
View User Account       
        
Add User Group      
Update User Group       
Remove User Group       
View User Group     
        
Add Vendor      
Update Vendor       
Deactivate Vendor       
View Vendor         
        
Add Location        
Update Location     
Deactivate Location     
View Location       
        
Add Product Category        
Update Product Category     
Remove Product Category     
View Product Category       
        
Add Product     
Update Product      
Deactivate Product      
View Product        
        
Add Status      
Update Status       
View Status 

Create Purchase Requisitions        
Modify Purchase Requistions     
Submit Purchase Requisitions        
View Purchase Requistions       
    
    
Cancel Purchase Order       
Send Purchase to Supplier       
View Purchase Orders        
            
View Purchase Requisitions      
Cancel Purchase Requisitions

Withdraw Items  
Receive Items   
View Inventory  

View Notifications          
Exipiration Alerts          
View Product Updates            
View Product Updates            
View Supplier Updates           
View Location Updates           
View Cancelled Purchase Requisitions            
View Approved Purchase Requisitions         
View Purchase Orders            
View Withdrawn items            
View Received Items         

View  Aging of Purchase Requisitions Report 
View Purchase Requisitions by Status Report 
View Aging of Purchase Orders   
View Purchase Order Status  
View Inventory Report   
View Vendor List report 
View Location List report   
View Product List report
```

My question is do I need to improve my work? Or it's all good to go?

Comment: Maybe you can ask on different forum. This forum only accept programming problem

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify it by creating a hierarchy of actors:

- Admin *is a kind of* User
- Inventory Officer *is a kind of* User

Then for all the "uses" associations in which both users are involved only need be drawn from the generic "User", while the specialist uses can be drawn from the specific actor sub-class.  In practice then use cases "System Configuration" and "Switch Portal" will be connected to "System Admin" and all others connected to "User".  It will be semantically identical, but simpler to comprehend with fewer "uses" associations.

Example:

[image: usecase]

Your internal relationships are not stereotype labelled. Most commonly these are either «extend» or «include» relations.  An extension is a use case that may occur in some instances of the primary use case, while an inclusion is a use case that occurs in all instances of the primary use case:

[image]

To help with the correct direction of the arrow in these relations, it helps to add an implicit 's' when you read it so that for example "*A extend**s** B*" and "*C include**s** D*.

So in this case for example presumably cancelling an order is an exceptional case that does not occur every time you send an order, so it seems likely that your untyped association should be «extend» and in the reverse direction to as you have it:

[image]

Whether that is a correct association is for you to determine - you have only given us the use cases

Comment: The main difference between includes and extends is not the optionality, but the dependency direction.  If use case A is being extended by B, then A doesn't know about B at all, and should not depend on the results of executing that use case.

Comment: @GeertBellekens - does that make anything in this answer incorrect (rather then possibly just incomplete)?  The directionality is in fact discussed - I am critiquing the OP's diagram here, not providing a complete course in UML.  The main point is that in the OP's diagram, in relationships are undefined.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your insightful suggestion! Organizing the actors into a hierarchy makes a lot of sense to simplify the use case diagram. I'll definitely adopt this approach to enhance clarity and streamline the visualization. If I encounter any challenges during the implementation, would it be okay to reach out for further guidance? Appreciate your help!

Comment: @darth-coder : your best bet would be to post further questions in SO.  SO is not a discussion forum and does not support DM.  You will always do better to canvas the whole SO community than to rely on a single member who may just be plain wrong and give poor advice.  Public discourse allows other views, corrections and solutions.

Comment: ... for example, it would be great if @GeertBellekens could post an answer. His biography suggests he has specific UML expertise, which I surely would not claim.  His earlier point may deserve clarification in an answer. I am not sure I understand his point.